# Find the matched value of an array with a given value

Tags: php

I have an array of value series like:

```
$series = [100,300,500,800,1000,3000,5000,10000,15000,20000];
```

Another value getting from DB like:

```
$point = $data[‘earned_point’];
```

I need the highest match from the series. such as I got a value from db (1500) the highest match of the value is 1000 in the series, so I need to get the $series[4] and make it

```
$reward = $series[4] * 0.1;
```

I'll run it in a loop to do it for all the values got from DB.

Comment: Please make an example from input and expected output.

Comment: What is the problem? Note that you need straight single or double quotes, no curly quotes.

Comment: `$reward = $series[$point] / 10`

Comment: I need the highest match from the series. such as I got a value from db (1500) the highest match of the value is 1000 in the series, so I need to get the $series[4] and make it $reward = $series[4] * 0.1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting alternate code as the accepted answer while is correct can be very inefficient if you are working with a large array.

```
<?php

function computeReward($series, $point, $percent = 0.1){
    arsort($series); // sort the series in reverse so we can pass any array and the highest number will be the first because we are looking for a number lower or equal to our point

    foreach($series as $min_point){
        if($min_point <= $point){
            return $min_point * $percent; // return the min_point * the percentage, this stops the loop there for being more efficient
        }
    }
}

$series = [100,300,500,800,1000,3000,5000,10000,15000,20000];
$point = $data['earned_point'];

$reward = computeReward($series, $point);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to get which highest $series item is equal or less than $point ?

```
<?php
$series = [100,300,500,800,1000,3000,5000,10000,15000,20000];
$point = $data['earned_point'];

foreach ($series as $min_point) {
   if ($point >= $min_point) {
      $matched_min_point = $min_point;
   }
}
$reward = $matched_min_point*0.1;
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: I need the highest match from the series. such as I got a value from db (1500) the highest match of the value is 1000 in the series, so I need to get the $series[4] and make it $reward = $series[4] * 0.1;